# Run python scripts between containers in compose

Tags: c#, python, .net, docker, anaconda

Let's say I have a docker container running: continuumio/anaconda3 which contains a python environment and a second docker container running a NET.Core application. They are clipped together through docker-compose. What would be the best approach to running python scripts inside of the anaconda environment right from within the .NET application?

I was already looking for some restful api for anaconda so I could just issue http requests but I could not find any. I also thought about just using the anaconda environment as a build step in the dockerfile of the .NET core application but I would like to hear your opinion on whenever that seems like a good idea. I don't want to use any service bus in this application. Maybe just issue ssh session to the python docker container and run ipython from terminal?

Comment: An HTTP API is a good way to do it. You don't need to find one, just implement it in something appropriate (Python and Flask?).